# Intent changes on user input, How to control that

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

**Que:** How to manage the flow of conversation, if in between the conversion the user type "hy" message the bot moves to welcome intent. How to stop that.

It should be such that the bot either go to next intent which is set using context or if doesn't match any training phrase then go to fallback intent and in fallback intent if the phrase matches move to the same intent where is stopped.

Can't able to find particular answers. Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: This depends on the setup of your bot, could you add some screenshots of your intents and an example of what is happening?

Comment: here are the screenshots first action -> [link](https://imgur.com/3fHHn5S)      secondaction --->    [link](https://imgur.com/tu7Ow4i)

Answer (score 0):

This issue is probably caused because your welcome intent includes the word "Hi" as a example phrase. It matches with "Hy" because the two words are very similar, it also isn't affected by any of the follow-up contexts that you included because the welcome intent itself has no input context. That means that the intent is available in every step of your conversation.

It will be hard to create a good fix for this since you would want the word "Hi" to trigger the welcome intent. What you could do is add "Hy" to your fallback intent, then it should always trigger the fallback intent instead. Sadly this only fixes it for the word "Hy" and not for other cases similair to your welcome intent phrases such as "He", "Ha", "Hai" etc.

Comment: Thank for you answer , there are multiple training phrases in welcome intent.I just want that if once user passes any intent it should not be appear again i.e. once the intent is passed either the user can go to next intent or to fallback then to next intent.

Comment: That isn't possible for the welcome intent (or an other intent that you start with). There has to be one intent that is always available to start the conversation. You could add it to the fallback to prevent it from restarting, but you can't remove the restart option itself.

Comment: Got it , Thanks help me in implementation.

Comment: Glad to hear that, if you would be so kind to close the question by accepting the answer. That would help me too :)